# How can I specify the digest to be used in a Dockerfile From line?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-image

From the docker [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from), I see I can set the From line to use a digest

```
FROM [--platform=<platform>] <image>[@<digest>] [AS <name>]
```

but trying to write something like

```
FROM ubuntu@sha256:9c152418e380 as ubuntu-22.04
```

doesn't seem to work and I get an error

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "ubuntu@sha256:9c152418e380": invalid reference format
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the full digest to `FROM`, not just the first few characters shown in most commands:

```
FROM ubuntu@sha256:9c152418e380c6e6dd7e19567bb6762b67e22b1d0612e4f5074bda6e6040c64a as ubuntu-22.04
```